# Approximate $p(X_{1000000}=2|X_1=1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Let the distribution on variables $(X_t)$ satisfy a Markov Chain, where each variable can take values {1,2}.And we are given that$ p(X_1)=0.5$

given that the transition matrix P is:

$P $=

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0.3 & 0.7\\
    0.6 & 0.4\\
     \end{matrix}
$$

1.Calculate $p(X_3=2)$. I'm not too sure if the answer is obvious here. Would I be correct to use Bayes Theorem?

2.Calculate $p(X_2=1|X_3=2)$. I got 0.6.

3.Calculate $p(X_1=1|X_3=2)$. I did $p(X_3=2|X_2=1)p(X_2=1|X_1=1) + p(X_3=2|X_2=2)p(X_2=2|X_1=1) = (0.7)(0.3) +(0.4)(0.7)= 0.49.$

4.Approximate $p(X_{1000000}=2|X_1=1)$

I know that under certain conditions, Markov chains converge to a limiting distribution, how can that help me figure this out?

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I attempted half of the questions. But i don't know where to start for question 4.

Comment: _Someone_ wrote a decent idea of where to start with 4 into your question, and you're the only one who has edited it...

Comment: Excuse me for being thick, but what are you talking about?

Comment: Did you not write the sentence "I know that under certain conditions, Markov chains converge to a limiting distribution"? Now you just need to consult your textbook to find out what the "certain conditions" are, and possibly for advice on how to find the limiting distribution.

Comment: Oh i see. Ill try that. Cheers

Comment: Im still not sure what to do. If i find the limiting distribution where do i go from there?

Comment: x @Neels: Look up in the limiting distribution what the limiting probability of $X=2$ is.